# set expandtab in .vimrc not taking effect

Tags: vim

For some reason the `set expandtab` command in my `.vimrc` file is not having any effect.

Here is my `.vimrc`:

```
" tab settings
set expandtab
set smarttab
set softtabstop=2
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set paste
```

However, when I run `vi` (no file name) the `:set` command emits:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  helplang=en         shiftwidth=2        ttyfast
  paste               tabstop=2           ttymouse=xterm2
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
```

which indicates that the `expandtab` option is not set. This is further confirmed by executing `:set expandtab?` which returns with `noexpandtab`.

I'm on OSX 10.10, and `vi --help` returns:

```
$ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 20 2016 11:11:25)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1847
Compiled by Homebrew
```

How come some settings in my .vimrc are being honored, but not `set expandtab`?

Comment: What happens when you use the command `:set expandtab` in vim? Might be some plugins overriding expandtab setting

Comment: It works if after starting up I run `:set expandtab`, but what I've posted is my entire `.vimrc` file and I haven't specified any file name, so I doubt any plugins are getting run.

Comment: Read `:help paste`. More generally, don't put anything in your `vimrc` that you don't fully understand.

Comment: @romainl Why did you post an acceptable answer as a comment?

Comment: @yolenoyer, I didn't have time to explain further. Eugene's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 48):

From the documentation on [`expandtab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27):

> This option is reset when the [`paste`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27)
>   option is set and restored when the [`paste`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) option is reset.

BTW, you probably don't want `paste` to be set all the time. It's commonly used for pasting into a terminal Vim to avoid messing up indentation, etc.

To conveniently turn `paste` on and off with one keypress you can add this shortcut (change `<F2>` to whatever key you want):

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

Comment: May want to look into [bracketed-paste](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste) to avoid this issue all together.  [Unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) also provides `yo`/`yO` commands for temporarily setting `'paste'`.

Comment: `set paste` in `~/.vimrc`override `set expandtab`

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same issue with neovim and no matter what I tried, I couldn't seem to fix this issue. It turns out there was an `.editorconfig` file with `indent_style=tab` in a parent directory. Fixed by adding a new `.editorconfig` in my directory with `root = true` (an alternative would have been to delete or edit the parent `.editorconfig` file).