# VIM ignores my tab-related settings in ~/.vimrc (and paste is not set)

Tags: vim, tabs

Here's my `~/.vimrc` on some machine:

```
set softtabstop=0 noexpandtab nosmarttab 
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4 
colorscheme murphy
```

... but when I edit files, tabs show up as 8 spaces, and typing in a tab produces for spaces. I looked around and found this question:

[set expandtab in .vimrc not taking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957844/set-expandtab-in-vimrc-not-taking-effect)

but I don't have `set paste` in my `~/.vimrc`, so that can't be the problem. What's causing this? And how can I enforce my tab preferences?

**Edit:** It seems my settings are only ignored for some filetypes, not for simple text files. How can I force my settings to apply to all filetypes? Or at least to specific types?

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose set shiftwidth?`?

Comment: @ohlec:   For a Python file, it's `shiftwidth=4\n         Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for a specific file type (rather than for all file types):

For file type `foo` Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup foo
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType foo setlocal softtabstop=0 noexpandtab nosmarttab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
augroup END
```

and replace `foo` with the file type in both occurrences.

**Note:** `foo` is not necessarily a file extension. For example, the Python language (`.py` typically), file type is `python`.